# Is profit from act for the sake of Allah or our deen halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, deeds

I heard that if someone doing something for the sake of Allah ONLY, one should not earn any worldly profit from it, while the otherwise statement as well. However, neither of them that I saw any foundation in reference of Quran or Hadith.

I wonder, is it true that one permissible, is Halal, to earn profit from act that is to do for the sake of Allah or our deen (religion)?

Comment: You may also learn some wiseness through this aya: http://quran.com/17/29

Answer (score 1):

There is no harm.

> لَيسَ عَلَيكُم جُناحٌ أَن تَبتَغوا فَضلًا مِن رَبِّكُم ۚ فَإِذا
> أَفَضتُم مِن عَرَفاتٍ فَاذكُرُوا اللَّـهَ عِندَ المَشعَرِ الحَرامِ ۖ
> وَاذكُروهُ كَما هَداكُم وَإِن كُنتُم مِن قَبلِهِ لَمِنَ الضّالّينَ
>
> **It is no sin for you that ye seek the bounty of your Lord (by
> trading)**. But, when ye press on in the multitude from 'Arafat,
> remember Allah by the sacred monument. Remember Him as He hath guided
> you, although before ye were of those astray. [(2:198)](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.pickthall/2:198)

The above ayah is generally accepted to mean merchandise of goods during Hajj - which must be done for the sake of Allah. There may exist difference of opinion as to whether the allowance is specific to pilgrimage or forms basis of a general permissibly of enjoying worldly profit in religious acts.

EDIT:
I'm editing this because someone claimed that the verse quoted above does not refer to Hajj as such but rather the "time around Hajj." The prohibitions during Hajj are unequivocally defined in the preceding verse.

> Hajj is [during] well-known months, so whoever has made Hajj
> obligatory upon himself therein [by entering the state of ihram],
> there is [to be for him] **no sexual relations and no disobedience and
> no disputing during Hajj**. And whatever good you do - Allah knows it.
> And take provisions, but indeed, the best provision is fear of Allah.
> And fear Me, O you of understanding. [(2:197)](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:197)

All the prohibitions are clearly stated here and if trade were absolutely prohibited it would have been included here. The verse about trade actually follows this verse and if you read them together, in order, Allah (swt) is saying *these things are disallowed for you and there is no harm if you indulge in trade*.

Comment: I corrected my vote, my understanding of that Ayah was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, when you do something halal you get rewarded for it, either you get money from it or not.

For example, if you die while working or going to work because you have a family and you want to assure them food and world benefits, then you will be conidered as a shahid (killed for the sake of Allah). Working is jihad.

If you refuse a job that contains haram, like working in a bank. Then you get rewarded for your choice, and everyday you have difficulties because of this job is rewarding for your patience.

If you do something for free or for a cheap amount, then the money you could have earned from your activity will be considered as Sadaka. But also if you sell goods to help muslims live a better life, choosing that goods in the intention to bring benefits to muslims will be rewarded, even if you make money from it.

Don't forget everything is free at the basis: vegetables and food grow for free, the land is given to us by God for free. What you pay is only the time people spent to make things: a farmer spends time with his sheeps, and that's why you pay for meat (even if the sheep was eating free stuff from the ground). When you buy a car, you pay people who took the free metal fromt the ground , that metal that God made available for us for free. you pay the engeneers for the time they spent to design the car, you pay for the people who designed the machines that make the car. but at the end you only pay poeple for their time.

So using your time for halal activities is a source of rewarding, even if you get payed for it, since you listened to God's orders and didn't follow the haram path

Comment: Jazaklahir bro! I wonder if you could reference on this one, because the rest make sense. "If you do something for free or for a cheap amount, then the money you could have earned from your activity will be considered as Sadaka. But also if you sell goods to help muslims live a better life, choosing that goods in the intention to bring benefits to muslims will be rewarded, even if you make money from it." Again, it make sense, however, some type of reference will help me undersatnd regarding the statement that if oneforgone profit partially then it will be the sadaka...

Comment: Salem bro!
Here is in al ba9ara: 271, that when you hide sada9a it is better for you (hiding it can be selling a good for cheaper that the market for poor people)
 {إِن تُبْدُواْ الصَّدَقَاتِ فَنِعِمَّا هِىَ وَإِن تُخْفُوهَا وَتؤْتُوهَا الفُقَرَاءِ فَهُوَ خَيرٌ لَّكُمْ} [سورة البقرة: 271]،

Also in the sourat ettawba 41, God says:
{انفِرُواْ خِفَافاً وَثِقَالاً وَجَاهِدُواْبِأَموَالِكُمْ وَأَنفُسِكُمْ فِي سَبِيلِ اللهِ ذَلِكُمْ خَيرٌ لَّكُمْ إِن كُنتُمْ تَعْلَمُونَ} [سورة التوبة:41]

Comment: Also the prophet said: the best sada9a is giving water ("sa9y" means to people or to animals or plants in arabic)

مجالات الصدقة الجارية

1- سقي الماء وحفر الآبار؛ لقوله صلى الله عليه وسلم: «أفضل الصدقة سقي الماء» [رواه أحمد وأبو داود والنسائي وابن ماجة:صحيح الجامع].

You can find more on the subject here: http://goo.gl/04JyA0

Comment: There is also a hadith you can use for reference when a spouse has sex with his spouse they gets rewarded in like 70 prayers `http://islamqa.info/ar/4536`. This is something they do for personal gain (sexual satisfaction, but because they are avoiding haram they get rewarded for them).

Answer (score 0):

> I heard that if someone doing something for the sake of Allah ONLY

You heard it right.

> (Saying): We feed you, for the sake of Allah only. **We wish for no reward nor thanks from you**; (Qur'an 76:9 More [Context](http://quran.com/76/6-12))

Another place you might have heard that from,

> He who spends his wealth for increase in self-purification, And have in his mind no favour from anyone for which a reward is expected in return, Except only the desire to seek the Countenance of his Lord, the Most High; He surely will be pleased (when he will enter Paradise). (Qur'an [92:18-21](http://quran.com/92/18-21))

So, from the above verses it is clear when you do something for the sake of Allah, you do it without expecting any reward nor thanks.

Yeah it is hard to believe and digest, but the truth.

But, in case if you're having financial crisis, and are unable to make enough for your living, then maybe you should focus on earning money through some good means rather than donating either your time or effort or money. (learn more [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/is-it-a-good-idea-or-allowed-to-give-money-as-sadqah-when-i-dont-have-much))

May the creator guide us all.