# is it a good idea or allowed to give money as sadqah when i don't have much?

Tags: sadaqah

I often give money as sadqah to mosque though in small amount or as a percentage whenever i earn.. still not a regular earning person. So, sometimes i feel like i need to save money..

But the thing is i feel psychologically unsecured and hapless often and that's why i do it to get psychological relief. And I feel like since i gave money to mosque (since i don't have that poor relative, everyone is very rich except our family)  so Allah will help me. So I get relief..

And it is also said that whatever you will spend for good, you will get everything back in more..

In this circumstances, is it a good idea or allowed to do so? since i saw a verse about it which means i think giving money is good after my own fulfillment.

Or, is there any alter way to get same reward? that will give me psychological relief too..

Comment: this is very common question which most people have... including my own family members...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **And they give food in spite of love for it to the needy, the orphan, and the captive** (Qur'an 76:8)

I remember your recent doubt about Qur'an 17:26 [here.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23043/11938)

Verily, your belief that Allah will help is true. Allah never lets believers' deeds wash away. But, he may or may not help you in this worldly life, but he will definitely help in the hereafter FOR SURE.

> Whoever desires the harvest of the Hereafter - We increase for him in his harvest. And whoever desires the harvest of this world - We give him thereof, but there is not for him in the Hereafter any share. (Qur'an 42:20)
>
> And the likeness of those who spend their wealth **seeking Allah's Pleasure** while they in their own selves are sure and certain that Allah will reward them (for their spending in His Cause), is the likeness of a garden on a height; heavy rain falls on it and it doubles its yield of harvest. And if it does not receive heavy rain, light rain suffices it. And Allah is All-Seer of (knows well) what you do. (Qur'an 2:265)

Finally, the most important verse for you and your case especially,

> **They ask you, [O Muhammad], what they should spend. Say, "Whatever you spend of good is [to be] for parents and relatives and orphans and the needy and the traveler. And whatever you do of good - indeed, Allah is Knowing of it.**" (Qur'an 2:215)

I would prefer to go in the order as described in the verse.

**BEWARE:**

> The Evil one(shaitan) threatens you with poverty and bids you to conduct unseemly. Allah promiseth you His forgiveness and bounties. And Allah careth for all and He knoweth all things. (Qur'an 2:268)

There are many things, which go wrong when one is poor. They might force themselves to do any evil thing, and the best part is, "THEY CONVINCE THEMSELVES THEY'RE NOT WRONG" and try to justify their deeds somehow. Few examples of evil things which one does during poverty are - Stealing, Lying, Taking Loans paying interest, other immoral behavior etc.

Now it feels like, it is better not to remain poor.

Anyways, make sure the money you donate to Mosques are utilized wisely like - **Mosques sometimes do unnecessary decorations and WASTE A LOT OF MONEY.** You are investing your valuable money for returns in the hereafter, but you need to make sure you invest the money at right places to get maximum benefits. Don't invest without proper market research.
You can also think for the trade off between a "New mosque at a different place where it is really needed" vs "expanding an existing mosque if really needed". <sub>[Can a Muslim association ask for donations to build a mosque?](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84960)</sub>

So, if at all you want to rethink or find some alternatives, then I would like you to know there are a number of poor Muslims(Al-Miskin - The Miser) out there across the globe who accept donations online.

Again to remind you, there is no compulsion on you to donate, when you can't afford to give out Zakah. You would also like to think about buying a pair of shoes to your family member if his/her shoes are worn out(just an example), or save a decent amount for tomorrow, or get/give a quality education(may include Islamic education) for yourself/your family member for their better future etc.

> Or, is there any alter way to get same reward? that will give me psychological relief too..

There is this book in the market which is a cook book of life hacks, best novel with interesting true stories aggregated, more than 800 million copies sold(hey you only pay for the paper) authored by none other than the creator himself. That famous book is called 'Qur'an'. You asked, I gave my opinion. If I'm given a wish, then I would definitely wish for 3 wishes and my wishes would never end. So, if I start writing all the ways you can get that psychological relief, it would never end. So, I just mentioned you the source(like the first wish).

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Hello bro, Thanks a lot for your kind answer.. thats very informative. Actually I suffer from frustration for many reasons.. I didn't get proper guidance and philosophical education from my family.. I used t think that what is the purpose of this life? My family was never able to give me the best answer.. actually no answer.. my father use to think that everything is god gifted, if god give it then it will be and if he isnt then it wont.. actually that made me mostly frustrated, stressed and hopeless.. since we live in hardships.

Comment: And after that when I started reciting Quran I felt better, though I found it hard to manage time.. but to be honest every time I read I find and learn new things.. it taught me the purpose of life, now Im understanding about decision making.. I used to suffer in decision making..

Comment: and when I got to know about many realistic things while reciting Qur'an like 'if i never try i wont be able to achieve anything'..'Allah helps him who help himself' and lots of things.. and my family and surroundings gave me so many wrong philosophies about life and its goal..I used to serf online and try to find out how to do best in everything.. And after reciting the Qur'an I realized that it is the best book for guidance..SubhanAllah..I wish I knew these from my early life.. then life could be more organized.. May Allah help us all.

Comment: Next, your dad is right. I want you to read Qur'an 3:33 to 3:44 (if you want you can continue further...). But of course... Qur'an 90:1-4... Have patience, and work hard... :)

Comment: Yes, Jazakallah khair(May Allah reward you with good).. Thanks to Allah, as He is helping me by other Muslims with knowledge..